# split json string into its constituent 1st child nodes and put keys into string array

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have a `Json` file which has unknown child nodes each of which have child nodes for an unknown depth.

I want to get the 1st level of child node names into an array.

How do i do this if i dont know their names or the number of child nodes - ie the json structure is dynamic?

eg json input

```
{
"childNode1":"value", "childNode2":"value", "childNode3":"value", "childNode4":"value"
}
```

expected output is equivalent to this array:

```
string[] jsonArray =
     new[] { "childNode1", "childnode2", "childNode3", "childnode4" };
```

The code i have will show me the children in the debugger 'locals', how can i get their keys and values?

```
JObject json = JObject.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath));
```

I can do it if i know what nodes I'm looking for but i don't in this case?

Comment: Can you please post expected input and output?

Comment: the input is there in the json example, the output from this example json is a 4 element string array ontaining the 1st level children key values

Comment: JSON.Net or JavaScriptSerializer?

Comment: @Fearghal your syntax was not valid. I've changed it, let us know if that's what you meant.

Comment: Apologies (switching to c# caught me out) that is exactly what i meant. In real life each of those nodes may have children of their own but for simplicity i excluded that

Comment: can the node names be duplicated?

Comment: Not the 1st level, i cant vouch for the next levels and below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do,

```
IEnumerable<string> ParsePropertyNames(string s)
{
    var o = JObject.Parse(s);
    return o.Properties().Select(p => p.Name);
}
```

which your could use like,

```
var results = ParsePropertyNames(yourString).ToArray();
```

Comment: what do i do with 'results'?

Comment: also, i take it yourstring is meant to be s in the ParsePropertyNames?

Comment: @Fearghal, thats up to you, its an array of strings.

Comment: `ParsePropertyNames` is a function, to which you could pass your string, which may be in a variable called `yourString`.

Comment: yes so in the function you should have  var o = JObject.Parse(yourString); =  var o = JObject.Parse(s); where s is passed in as param.

Answer (score 3):

If you deserialize the object as a dictionary, you can get the keys easily. Here's an example using [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json).

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(s);
string[] jsonArray = dict.Keys.ToArray();
```

Depending on what you want to do with the object, the second line might be redundant.

If you already have it as a [`JObject`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm), you can get the names like this:

```
JObject json = // something
string[] jsonArray = ((IDictionary<string, JToken>)json).Keys.ToArray(); // or
string[] jsonArray = json.Properties().Select(x => x.Name).ToArray();
```

Comment: where do i put my json string?

Comment: s is your json string.

Comment: Got an error, dud to one of the nodes, im not sure why jsonserialiser cares but....'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: C. Path '', line 0, position 0.'

Comment: I have a JObject created, and i can see in my debugger its children, there must be an easy way to get from here the child nodes into an array? oupdated the question

Comment: fantastic, that works a treat and allows me to keep my jobjects for further inspection.

Comment: @Fearghal Glad to help! You should put the mark on whatever answer you think is best.